# Scope error using Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I believe my problem relates to scope somehow, as I'm a js newbie. I have a tiny backbone.js example where all I am trying to do is print out a list of items fetched from the server.

```
$(function(){
    // = Models =
    // Video
    window.Video = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
            return {
                title: 'No title',
                description: 'No description'
            };
        },
        urlRoot: 'api/v1/video/'
    });

    // VideoList Collection
    // To be extended for Asset Manager and Search later...
    window.VideoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Video,
        url: 'api/v1/video/'
    });

    // = Views =
    window.VideoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',

        render: function(eventName) {
            $(this.el).html("");
            _.each(this.model.models, function(video) {
                $(this.el).append(new VideoListRowView({model:video}).render().el);
                }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });

    // VideoRow
    window.VideoListRowView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "li",

        template: _.template("id: <%= id %>; title: <%= title %>"),

        className: "asset-video-row",

        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    // Router
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes:{
            "":"assetManager"
        },

        assetManager:function() {
            this.assetList = new VideoList();
            this.assetListView = new VideoListView({model:this.assetList});
            this.assetList.fetch();
            $('#content').html(this.assetListView.render().el);
        }
    });

    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();

    // The following works fine:
    window.mylist = new VideoList();
    window.mylistview =  new VideoListView({model:window.mylist});
});
```

If I access `mylist.fetch(); mylist.toJSON()` from the console, mylist populates fine. I can tell that `this.assetList.fetch()` is accurately fetching the data from the backend, but it doesn't appear to be adding the objects to `this.assetList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fetch` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) on Backbone collections is asynchronous:

> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, resetting the collection when they arrive. [...] Delegates to Backbone.sync under the covers, for custom persistence strategies.

And [Backbone.sync](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) says:

> **Backbone.sync** is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses `(jQuery/Zepto).ajax` to make a RESTful JSON request.

So `fetch` involves an (asynchronous) AJAX call and that means that you're trying to use the collection before `fetch` has retrieved the data from the server. Note that fetch supports `success` and `error` callbacks so you can do this instead:

```
var self = this;
this.assetList.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        $('#content').html(self.assetListView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Or you could bind a callback to the collection's `reset` event as `fetch` will reset the collection. Then render your `assetListView` when the collection's `reset` event is triggered.

Also, your `assetList` is a collection so you should be doing:

```
this.assetListView = new VideoListView({collection: this.assetList});
```

and:

```
window.VideoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html("");
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(video) {
            // ...
```

Comment: So you make good suggestions for how to organize binding the event, etc., but if you explained what my problem is I'm afraid I've missed it. ***

Nevermind, it clicked. It's asynchronous so that the rendering event that follows is not waiting for fetch() to complete. Thank you! I'll test it and come back to mark correct if it works out.

Comment: Spot on. From here on out I'll be using the event bindings.

Comment: @akoumjian: Right, the root of your problem is that you're trying to use the collection before `fetch` has fetched it from the server. I've clarified that for posterity. Doing as much as possible through the events system will save you a lot of trouble.